# Regular Expression to pull data in parenthesis

Tags: regex, excel, openoffice-calc

I have a dataset of about 3000 rows in openoffice, each set MAY contain data within paranthesis of (XXXv) where XXX can be any 3 digit number (usually 110, 220, 115, 120)

I need to simply ignore everything else in that field, and find/replace down to only the value.

Other paranthesis may exist within the data. most data is in HTML format, in a csv file currently. Some fields may not contain a value either.

```
EX: ITEM NUMBER 38 (115v) - (SKU)
(simplified, many will be 100-1000 characters in length, in html)
```

=IF statements might also work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, regex seems like the best way to go. The regex should be something like `.*\(([0-9][0-9][0-9])v\).*`. The captured group will be the value you're looking for.

Comment: .*\(([0-9][0-9][0-9])v\).*

would it not need a 2nd paranthesis after the 3rd value? I don't know enough about regex to say, but just looking at it kinda suggests?
    .*\(([0-9][0-9][0-9]))v\).*

also, what would I put in the "replace" field?

EDIT: it does not need the 2nd paranthesis, didn't see the 1 on the end :)

Comment: The parentheses around the numbers captures it. The escaped parentheses match actual characters in the string, pulling out the XXX from "...(XXXv)...". You can replace with the first captured group, `\1`.

Comment: replacing with \1 does not appear to be working, it simply replaces the entire string with the value "\1"

http://screencast.com/t/HZEV2iLC1Uk

Comment: Normally `\1` refers to the value captured by the parentheses, but apparently it's not so easy in OpenOffice. See http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=61857 .

Comment: well thats a hassle - for anybody who might come across this later, simply copy the column to notepad++, run it there, copy it back to openoffice/excel.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

use this regular expression for replace `(?<=\()\d{3}(?=v\))`
if your regex engine don't know lookbehind, use `=\(\d{3}v\)` with replace (`value`v)

Comment: I might be missing something but what happens if the string were "ITEM NUMBER 213 (124v) (121)"?

Comment: would be selected only 3 digit, "ITEM NUMBER `213` (`124`v) (`121`)" i mark matches

Comment: But the OP only wants the 124.